# Comment utiliser « eu » ?

Tags: sens, participe-passé

Dans la phrase «  C’est tout simplement parce que vous n’avez pas **eu** le temps ou parce que vous n’avez pas trouvé le temps. » 
comment utiliser « **eu** » ? Qu'est-ce que signifie « eu » ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux savoir exactement, le sens de [eu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir) ou le sens de *avoir le temps* ?

Comment: J'ai aussi beaucoup de mal à comprendre la question. Donnons une chance au contributeur de préciser sa pensée.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« Eu » n'est qu'une des quatre formes du participe passé du verbe « avoir », dont la conjugaison entière se trouve [ici](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=avoir).

*Les quatre formes*

- eu, eus, eue, eues

Le verbe avoir a un grand nombre de significations, comme on peut s'en faire une idée à partir de l'entrée de ce mot dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir). La signification principale est celle de « posséder », qui comprend deux grand domaines de ce concept, parmi d'autres ; le premier est celui de la possession d'objets, d'argent, de propriété, cela du fait d'une loi écrite ou d'une règle ou du simple fait du contrôle plus ou moins total que l'on a sur une chose. Le second est celui des attributs, ces choses que l'on possède en tant que caractéristiques personnelles.

1: possession d'objets

- Il **a** une maison, mais elle en **a** deux parce qu'elle est plus riche.
- Il **a** des billes dans sa poche.

2: possession de caractéristique

- Ces personnes **ont** un mauvais caractère.
- Anne **a** les yeux bleus.

L'emploi du participe passé du verbe « avoir », qui est un verbe transitif, c'est à dire qui s'utilise avec ce qui est appelé un complément d'objet direct, est sujet à une règle concernant ce complément d'objet direct. Si le complément est placé avant le verbe il est nécessaire de faire un accord en genre et en nombre avec le complément, sinon il n'y a pas d'accord et c'est la forme « eu » qui est utilisée. Ci-dessous se trouve la correspondance des formes avec les genres et nombres.

- masculin singulier       - eu
- pluriel           - eus
- féminin singulier          - eue
- pluriel              - eues

*COD après le verbe*

- J'ai eu une bonne **note**.
- J'ai eu des **zéros** en histoire.
- Elles ont eu des **fleurs** pour leur anniversaire.

*COD avant le verbe*
Quand le cod est avant le verbe c'est soit un pronom relatif ou personnel soit un cod sous la forme de nom employé dans une exclamation ou une question ([réf.](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_05_accord_du_participe_passe_avec_avoir.shtml)).

- La bonne note **que** j'ai *eue* n'était pas méritée.
- Jai eu des zéros en histoire ; je **les** ai *eus* parce je ne savais pas mes leçons.
- Quelle belles **fleurs** elles ont *eues* pour leur anniversaire !

*Quelques exemples de plus*
- Le **cheval de bois** qu'il a *eu* à Noël était tout rouge.
- Elle a *eu* une **poussette** comme cadeau.
- Quelle **poussette** a-t-elle *eue* comme cadeau, la grande ou la petite ?

Dans la phrase « C’est tout simplement parce que vous n’avez pas eu le temps ou parce que vous n’avez pas trouvé le temps. » l'idée de possession est un peu différente de celles dans les cas importants introduits ci-dessus. Il s'agit de circonstances personnelles qui laissent du temps libre ; lorsque l'on jouit de telles circonstances on dit, pour exprimer cela « on a le temps ». Comme le cod « temps » est postposé il n'y a pas d'accord ; s'il y avait un accord, de toute façon cela ne changerait rien puisque « temps » est un substantif masculin singulier.